# Find the variance of number of times someone must throw a die until $2$ has appeared $6$ times.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I am learning variance for the first time so I am unable to think through this. Can someone maybe help point me in the right direction?

I am able to think this if I had to roll the die multiple times, but in this question I have to think more of as the die landing on a specific number and in my head when I am thinking about this I am getting infinite possibilities and so I am getting confused

Update: My latex isn't perfect. First we see that getting 2 the first is a geometric distribution, with a corresponding pmf:

$(\frac{5}{6})^n * (\frac{1}{6}) $

Now we want to repeat this to get the 2 a second time. Multiplying the two distributions, we obtain:

$(\frac{1}{36})(\frac{5}{6})^{2n}$

The expected value is then:

$E[x] = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} n * (\frac{1}{36})* (\frac{5}{6})^{2x} = \frac{25}{121}$

$E[x^2] = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} n^2 * (\frac{1}{36})* (\frac{5}{6})^{2x} = \frac{1535}{1331}$

So my answer is $\frac{16150}{14641}$

Comment: Hi! Can you figure out what the variance is for the number of times the die must be rolled until $2$ has appeared one time? Start with that first. What kind of distribution does that random variable have? (Incidentally, I'm assuming that there is one die; "dice" is plural, but you said "a dice". If there are two dice, the result changes, but the approach is the same.)

Comment: @BrianTung This should be geometric right? Infinite sum? And one die only

Comment: Geometric, yes. What do you mean by "infinite sum"? Incidentally, as you figure things out, edit your post to include your findings. That will help prevent your question from receiving down-votes and close-votes.

Comment: @BrianTung
This was my attempt. Also, my latex isn't perfect. First we see that getting 2 the first is a geometric distribution, with a corresponding pmf:

\[(\frac{5}{6})^n * (\frac{1}{6})\]

Now we want to repeat this to get the 2 a second time. Multiplying the two distributions, we obtain:

\[(\frac{1}{36})(\frac{5}{6})^{2n} \]

The expected value is then:
\[E[x] = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} n * (\frac{1}{36})* (\frac{5}{6})^{2x} = \frac{25}{121}\]
\[E[x^2] = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} n^2 * (\frac{1}{36})* (\frac{5}{6})^{2x} = \frac{1535}{1331}\]

So my answer is $\frac{16150}{14641}$

Comment: @BrianTung Can you look at my post again and help me figure out what I might have done wrong?

Comment: The time to get the second $2$ (counting from the first roll after the first $2$) is independent of the time to get the first $2$. So the variances are additive.

Comment: Also: You're squaring the probabilities. But that's not what the second moment is. The second moment is the expected value of the square: $\sum_{t=1}^\infty t^2 p_t$, not $\sum_{t=1}^\infty tp_t^2$.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to think of this. Let's start with a geometric distribution, since that's what you mentioned; it's a good choice for modeling the waiting time for our first $2$.

Say we rolled the die a couple times and got a $2$.  Then we have to roll it some more and get another $2$.  That's also a geometric distribution.  If we add the number of rolls from our first geometric variable to the number from our second, we get the number of rolls to obtain two $2$s.  In other words, if you're looking for $Y_2$, the number of rolls required to get two $2$s, then $Y = X_1 + X_2$, where $X_i \sim \text{geom}(1/6)$.

Of course, you can go as far as you like with this process. Your title says you're looking for six $2$s, so we can just continue in the same fashion:  Let $Y_6 = X_1 + \dots + X_6$, with each $X_i \sim \text{geom}(1/6)$.

Using the linearity of the expectation operator, $E[Y_6] = E[\sum X_i] = \sum E[X_i] = 6 E[X_1]$, since each $X_i$ has the same distribution.

Since the number of rolls to get one $2$ has no bearing on the number of rolls required to get the next -- that is, since all $X_i$s are mutually independent -- we can write $\text{Var}(Y_6) = \sum \text{Var}(X_i) = 6 \text{Var}(X_1)$.

At this point, you can compute the mean and variance as you normally would.  Again, each $X_i$ has the same distribution, so you can just pick an index and go with it.

Whatever you do, though, be careful that you know what the pmf is.  The pmf you start with in your question is not a pmf:  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1/6) (5/6)^n = 5/6$, not $1$.*  Moreover, there are *two* ways to write the pmf of the geometric distribution, depending on whether you're counting trials or failures before a success.  I'm guessing you maybe counting the former, but... just make sure :).

Now, the geometric distribution has been studied pretty thoroughly.  That means, whatever your source is, it may well include the formula for the mean and variance of any geometric random variable.  If you have access to that information, once you've identified the problem (as we have), the solution is easy.  If you have to compute it yourself, though, you may find the factorial moment $E[X(X-1)]$ useful in computing the variance.

Alternatively -- and here I've arrived at the other way to think about your question -- if you know that there is a name for the sum of geometric random variables -- that is, the negative binomial distribution, which counts the number of trials until the $r$th success -- then you can avail yourself of the formulas for *that* distribution's mean and variance.

---

- Squaring the individual probabilities, as you attempted, also won't work.  To take a simple example:  Let's say $p_1 + p_2 = 1$, with both $p_i > 0$.  If they're both positive, they must also be less than $1$.  Squaring them, then, will yield $p_i^2 < p_i$, and so their sum will also be less than $1$.